# Sqoop import Error during import from SAP Hana to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, import, sqoop, hana

I would like to import table data from SAP Hana to Hadoop. For one table, I was able to execute query successfully and data ingested into Hadoop from SAP Hana. But when I am trying for another table I am getting the following issue.Facing issue from yesterday.

Here are the query & Error as follows.I request to help me in this regard

Query:

```
sqoop import --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver \
--connect "hostname/schemaname" \
--username teja \
--password mypwd \
--table test \
--target-dir "output" \
--m 1;
```

Error:

> Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "/":

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `test` name of your table?

Comment: table name : test

Comment: put `--verbose` in the end of the command and share full logs

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --query argument instead of --table command and see if that works for you:

```
sqoop import --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver \
--connect "<hostname>:<port>?currentschema=<schemaname>" \
--username teja \
--password mypwd \
--query "select * from test where $conditions" \
--target-dir "output" \
--m 1;
```